# Why is Thiruman Sacred?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, practice, sri-vaishnava, tilak

What is purpose/reason of using [Thiruman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srivaishnava_Urdhva_Pundra#Thiruman) katti for making Urdhwapundra or Namam, What is relation of Thiruman to Shriman Narayana? How is it holy clay?

Comment: @@Yogi - Thiruman or Naamam which is worn on forehead and also other parts of the body ( Twelve Urdhva pundras) is considered as the foot/feet of Lord Vishnu. request you to pls check satcharitra Raksha of Swami Vedanta Desika. I think, it gives all the necessary clarifications on Thiruman it's efficacy along with references from Shruti, Smriti, ithihasa and agamas.

Comment: @Krishna Why is gopi chandan forbidden instead of thiruman?

Comment: @@Yogi-didn't know that Gopi chandan is forbidden.

Comment: Dada i have found Urdhwapundra mahtmya while searching , its said that laxmi , moksha and hari resides in   Urdhwapundra ,Even procedure is there ,if you want i will write answer. Long time no see!!!

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Hi...Where did you find urdhwapundra mahatmya?

Comment: I think in Hari Bhakti Vilasa. But i will search in agama books , i am a little busy right now for 1 week , but in between i will try. :-)

Comment: Dada Kasa kai? According to this author ,  Vaishnavas believe that thiruman protects them from all sort of spirits and evil. - 
https://youtu.be/nfQV0xWPMAU
seek  3:38 & 10:28

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I am fine how are you? I am. Aware of that... Actually I am going to delete this question

Comment: No need to del. the q. , actually "What is relation of Thiruman to Shriman Narayana?" is interesting part. Let's hope that someone will answer it.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar yes pancharatra texts answer that so I would want to delete it

Answer (score 1):

Srimathe Ramanujaya namaha!

Thiruman is obtained from medium grade metamorphic rock. It is defined by having more than 50% platy and elongated minerals. It is found mainly in Melkote, Karnataka.

Pundraka -(Urdhva pundra in Sanskrit), (Thiruman, or Thirunamam in Tamil) - ritual mark, means holy mud, is applied on the foreheads of devotees of Sri Narayana, and Lord Vishnu himself wears it on His forehead.

Devotees apply it as a mark of respect to Lord Vishnu, denoting they are holding His Lotus Feet on their forehead. The two white lines represent the feet of the Lord, and the red line represents Lakshmi Thaayar who is ever present with Him. According to other sources, the left line represent Lord Brahma, the right line Lord Siva and the middle portion is where Lord Narayana dwells with Mother Lakshmi.
The meaning of Him wearing it is to show the Bhaktha that the protection to him is from all possible direction, if he surrenders to the Lord.
Each thiruman placed on the body represents a different name of Sriman Narayana:

forehead Kesava
belly Narayana
chest  Madhava
throat Govinda
right side Vishnu
right arm Madhusudana
right shoulder Trivikrama
left side Vamana
left arm Sridhara
left shoulder Hrisikesha
upper back Padmanabha
lower back Damodara

Comment: thanks for the effort but this is not the answer how do you prove relation of thiruman with shriman narayana??although some factual details are correct but some are incorrect like the trideva representation is weird  and nothing is cited to support your answer.

Comment: GruthOdhvapuNdra: paramESithAram nArAyaNam saankhya yOgAdhi gagyam |
 jnAthvA vimuchyEtha nara: samasthai: samsaara paaSairiha chaiva vishNu: ||

Comment: Yaga, charity, penance, daily sacrifice, taking food,offering of water to manes (argyam)  etc., is all null and void if one does without wearing Urdhva pUndram. Libations means pouring of water in honour of God. Manes means spirit of the dead (deceased Father,Mother. Grand father, Grand mother, . pithru tharpaNam means offering water with sesame seeds to those twelve Pithru dEvathAs. Hence, wearing Urdhva pUndram is essential. The shape of Urdhva pUndra should be in the shape of HaripAdakruthi (in the shape of the Lotus Feet of Sriman Narayanan). From Pancharatna Samhitha

Comment: Okay I will try to find this panchartara samhita you mentioned but I doubt there is something like pancharatra samhita. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra#Pancharatra_Texts

Comment: You should cite sources.