# Which purana(s) mention story of GarudaAlwar carrying Tiruman mountain from Vaikuntha

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

[Tiruman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/why-is-thiruman-sacred) literally means 'Sacred/holy' (Tiru)+ (man)'Sand/Rock/Clay', is used by Sri Vaishnavas for applying Urdhwapundra on body.

I've heard a story about Garudalwar aka Garuda Swamy bringing Tiruman hills from Vaikuntha and establishing them in Melkote. Which purana/Itihasa etc discuss this story, add the full story in your answer.

Comment: Garuda brought Venkatadri from Vaikunta as mentioned in Venkatachala Mahatyma. Maybe Tiruman also came with Venkatadri.

Comment: Btw, can you use Sanskrit words besides Tamil words, as everyone can't understand tamil?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I've edited confusing words. Yeah that.might be the case Garudalwar might have bought melkote hills along with Venkatanchala parvata

Comment: @SreeCharan He certainly deserves being called swamy

Comment: But no one calls like that. Garuda alwar is the word for Vaishnavas but not correct here. Only perumal is swami. Others are Swa. All the bhaktas are called alwars. Vishwaksena is called Perumal and alwar at the same time.

Comment: @Yogi Garudar is also called PeriyaThiruvadi